# Seleccionar opciones de un combo multiple en Extjs v4, mediante un string separado por comas

Tags: javascript, sql, extjs

Estoy trabajando con Extjs 4.0 y tengo un combobox que guarda datos en un campo VARCHAR(MAX). Al ser de selección múltiple al guardar los datos seleccionados, se guardan como una cadena separada por comas.
Ejemplo:

```
O-09 Retencion, O-07 titulo de renta, O-08 timbre nacional
```

hasta allí ningún problema, éste existe hasta que quiero cargar los datos, de nuevo en el combo para poder modificar los valores. Ya que el rawValue, si lo puedo modificar, pero quisiera que se **PUEDAN DEJAR SELECCIONADAS LAS OPCIONES** que traigo en la cadena, las opciones no tienen un ID asi que tengo el siguiente código para seleccionar las opciones,

```
    function seleccionOpcionComboRespFiscalesCol(comboResponsabilidadFiscal, filaSeleccionada) {
        var seleccionados = filaSeleccionada.split(",");
        var aux = comboResponsabilidadFiscal.store.data.items;
        var auxDeSeleccion;
        //
        for (var i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
            for (var item in seleccionados) {
                auxDeSeleccion = seleccionados[item].trim();
                if (aux[i].data.tx_responsabilidadFiscal == auxDeSeleccion) {
                    Ext.getCmp('cmb_responsabilidadFiscalCol').select(aux[i].data.tx_responsabilidadFiscal);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Donde **comboResponsabilidadFiscal** es el objeto del combobox y **filaSeleccionada**, trae en su valor la cadena que obtengo de la base de datos, la que esta separada por comas

Debugueando, según si lo hace!,**(el código entra en la parte en la que dice que la cadena del combo es la misma que la cadena de la obtenida en la base de datos)**. pero al terminarlo solo se selecciona la primera opción, en el combo también solo aparece la opción primera en el rawValue, como si actuará como un combo normal. Está función se manda a llamar al momento de expandir el combo

los valores del combo son los siguientes

```
O-07    titulo de renta
O-08    timbre nacional
O-09    Retencion
O-14    Informante
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo he resuleto! se crea un array con las opciones que se cargarán dentro del combo

```
function seleccionOpcionComboRespFiscalesCol(comboResponsabilidadFiscal, filaSeleccionada) {
        var seleccionados = filaSeleccionada.split(",");
        var aux = comboResponsabilidadFiscal.store.data.items;
        var auxDeSeleccion;
        var valores = [];
        //
        for (var i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
            for (var item in seleccionados) {
                auxDeSeleccion = seleccionados[item].trim();
                if (aux[i].data.tx_responsabilidadFiscal == auxDeSeleccion) {
                    valores.push(aux[i].data.tx_responsabilidadFiscal);
                }
            }
        }
        Ext.getCmp('cmb_responsabilidadFiscalCol').setValue(valores);
    }
```

Asi quedará la función y el resultado es el deseado.